# In DRF(django-rest-framework), AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute '~~' How to solve it?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF and be front of AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute '~~'.

**my error page and code**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'blog',
 'account',
 'taggit',
 'friendship',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
  52.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/blog/views.py" in post_list
  37.         return Response(serializer.data)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  700.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  239.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  618.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in <listcomp>
  618.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  463.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in get_attribute
  157.         return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  83.                 instance = getattr(instance, attr)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /blog/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'
```

I wonder how to make `serializers.py` codes.

I already studied : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

But I don't understand what I should do. Where should I put `serializers.py`?
And how to make my serializers code? Or maybe `models.ForienKey` is unavailable on using DRF?

**blog/views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_list(request, format=None):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        lat = request.POST.get('user_lat', '13')
        lon = request.POST.get('user_lon', '15')
        userpoint = GEOSGeometry('POINT(' + lat + ' ' + lon + ')', srid=4326)
        i=1

        while i:
            list_i = Post.objects.filter(point__distance_lte = (userpoint, D(km=i)))
            list_total = str(',' + ' list_i')
            post_list = list(chain(list_total))
            if len(post_list) >= 0 :
                break

        serializer = PostSerializer(post_list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You need to show the post_list function in blog/views.

Comment: Please do not post long lines of code here as it becomes a very tedious task for us to go through it. You may consider going through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DanielRoseman , added blog/views.py sorry i didn't know what code is needed..

Comment: @Amal.R , Sorry. I'm very new in programming something, so i didn't have a idea of what code has to be on question. I will remember your advice so i'll try to make good question and codes next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your serializer, or where you put it. The error traceback is telling you that the error happens in the view.

So, in your post_list view, you build up a list (also called `post_list`) which is populated by a list of strings. Then you try and put it through the PostSerializer, which of course is expecting a queryset of Posts.

I'm not sure what the point of the list is; seems like you should be passing the Posts directly to the serializer.

Comment: Thank you, but i have to use my custom 'post_list'. Is there any way of making this post_list 'serialized'?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to "serialize"? Your list consists entirely of a series of identical strings, all of which are `", list_i"`. What's the point?

Comment: First, `, list_i` is to meet grammer of itertools - chain(from : https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html) to sum my lists into just one list. For example, post_list that are from 'userpoint' near 5km list(+ my custom option like.. author's name is bus terminal) and post_list that are from 'userpoint' near 10km list .. like this way maybe i want sum 5-7 lists to only one list. So finally i want serialize that last one list(result of itertools.).  Sorry for my poor english expressions.. I hope it's sufficient for you to understand my idea.

Comment: From my comment above, post_list -> list_1, list_2 . I mean, list_1, list_2, + ... + list_(maybe)6 -> last one list(as my code,  = post_list)  and ths post_list  is what i want serialize. Actually i want to make android application, i need restful api.